# My ISP is forcing me to buffer tcp data before sending it

Tags: java, networking, tcp, wireshark

I have a Java TCP game server, I use `java.net.ServerSocket` and everything runs just fine, but recently my ISP did a some kind of an upgrade, where, if you send two packets very fast for the same TCP connexion, they close it by force.

This is why a lot of my players are disconnected randomly when there's a lot of traffic in game (when there is a lot of chance that the server will send 2 packets at same time for the same person)

Here is an example of what I mean:
If I do something like this, my ISP will close the connexion for no reason to both client and server side:

```
tcpOut.print("Hello.");
tcpOut.flush();

tcpOut.print("How are you?");
tcpOut.flush();
```

But it will work just fine if i do something like this:

```
tcpOut.print("Hello.");
tcpOut.flush();

Thread.sleep(200);

tcpOut.print("How are you?");
tcpOut.flush();
```

Or this:

```
tcpOut.print("Hello.");
tcpOut.print("How are you?");
tcpOut.flush();
```

This only started a couple of weeks ago when they (the ISP) did some changes to the service and the network. I noticed using Wireshark that you have to have at least ~150ms time between two packets for same TCP connexion or else it will close.

1)Do you guys know what is this called ? does is it even have a name ? Is it legal ?

Now I have to re-write my game server knowing that I use a method called: `send(PrintWriter out, String packetData);`

2)Is there any easy solution to ask java to buffer the data before it sends it to clients ? Or wait 150ms before each sending without having to rewrite the whole thing ? I did some googling but I can't find anything that deals with this problem. Any tips or information to help about this would be really appreciated, btw speed optimisation is very crucial. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Your local TCP/IP stack will buffer and delay the outgoing data according to the perceived network speed, and unless you are messing with tcpSetNoDelay it will generally delay packets further so as to coalesce them. What are you seeing that makes you think there is a forced close? And can your users really type 6 lines a second? or is it just your application unnecessarily flushing after every newline?

Comment: Thank you EJP for your comment. I am 100% positive the ISP is closing the connexion, I see it on Wireshark when I get a red Reset Packet. I also did some testings.. Sometimes the data is appended into one packet as you just said (local TCP/IP stack) but sometimes it doesn't when my server has alot of flushing to do. It is an MMORPG Game, so when users talk, move, attack, etc at same time on the map, there is alot of flushings to do, so at some point two packets are sent at same time to one player, and my ISP closes that socket.

Comment: And by "same time" I mean with a delay less than 100ms.

Comment: OK but why flush() between the 'Hello' and the 'How are you?' lines?

Comment: The flush() is just an example to show what I mean. I have a Player.send(data) method that is called, and inside of it is a print+flush. So it is likely that I have more than one Player.send() as an answer to one request.

Comment: Then what you need to do is reorganize your flushing. For example you could make your processing per request two passes: first the write then the flush. The redundant flushes would do nothing. This is more efficient both on the network and at the clients anyway regardless of your ISP difficulties.

Comment: Wow. That's ridiculous. Does this impact telnet or SSH sessions as well? If so, complain. Another thing you could try is to move your game to another port. (say 23?) If that works then maybe this TCP abuse is limited to certain ports.

Comment: never had such an experience but is sure sounds like either some security measure (prevent DoS attacks to originate from the ISPs network) and/or some QoS configuration gone seriously wrong...

Comment: @EJP: Thank you. But unfortunately my game server code is very big and compilcated, with multithreadings etc (years of constant work) It will take ages to re-write everything. I was hoping for a fast solution on java/socket side. Or maybe a windows solution for this.

Comment: @Mike I'm using windows. This limitation is on every TCP port. I even made an other application using Winsock and Visual Basic 6.0, and even C# to debug this thing. When I send two packets (with less than 200ms in between) and flush them without buffering them, it still closes the connexion.

Comment: @Yahia Maybe you are right. I'm sure it's an other QoS abuse, my ISP has a history with that.

Comment: @Reacen the best way out is NOT to be found in coding a workaound IMHO but in relocating to an ISP with good manners and track record IMHO !

Comment: What about large file transfer ? Because of TCP windowing, a burst of packets (2, 4, 8... packets at a time) are sent before any round-trip to optimize transfer time with large bandwidth. Another question - what kind of link technology and contractual bandwidth do you have with that ISP ?

Comment: Can you upload your wireshark dumps somewhere so we could take a look?

Comment: Could also be a bug at the isp end. You really should call them up and discuss it.

Comment: Is upping your MTU an option?  Sending fewer, larger packets?  This is a change you can effect at the OS level.

Comment: Changing the MTU is only possible in your own network - for instance "jumbo frames". When communicating with the "outside world", there is high chance that the traffic is fully reshaped by a modem or a router to match ISP requirements...

Comment: This isn't an answer persay, but do the Terms of Service for your ISP allow running of a 'server' ?  Mine sure doesn't...unless you upgrade to their 'Business Class'.  If I had to guess, then that'd be my bet. Any chance of switching ISPs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a `Writer` wrapper implementation to keep track of last `flush` call timestamp. A quick implementation is to add a wait call to honor the 150 ms delay between two consecutive flushes.

```
public class ControlledFlushWriter extends Writer {
    private long enforcedDelay = 150;
    private long lastFlush = 0;
    private Writer delegated;

    public ControlledFlushWriter(Writer writer, long flushDelay) {
        this.delegated = writer:
        this.enforcedDelay = flushDelay;
    }

    /* simple delegation for other abstract methods... */

    public void flush() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now < lastFlush + enforcedDelay) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(lastFlush + enforcedDelay - now);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // probably prefer to give up flushing 
                // instead of risking a connection reset !
                return;
            }
        }
        lastFlush = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.delegated.flush();
    }

}
```

It now should be enough to wrap your existing `PrintWriter` with this `ControlledFlushWriter` to work-around your ISP QoS without re-writing all your application.

After all, it sounds reasonable to prevent a connection to flag any of its packet as urgent... In such a condition, it is difficult to implement a fair QoS link sharing.

Answer (score 5):

If your ISP imposes such quality of service policies and you have no way to negotiate them with it, I propose you enforce that rules on your side too with TCP/IP stack QoS configuration.

A flush marks your TCP packet as urgent (URG flag) so that it is sent whatever the buffer/TCP window state is. Now you have to tell your operating system or any network equipment on the line to either

- ignore (or simply reset) the urgent flag when the previous packet has been sent in the last 150 ms and do some buffering if necessary
- delay the delivery of consecutive urgent packets to honor the 150 ms constraint.

Probably an expensive software for Windows exists to do so. Personally, I think putting a Linux box as router between your Windows workstations and modem with the [appropriate QoS settings](http://lartc.org/lartc.html) in iptables and qdisc will do the trick.